# Unable to show the saved data in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdown in gridview, which gets data through web method,but after saving data, i am unable to show saved data in gridview.

Here is the code behind for gridview bind through web method:

```
 Private Sub BindData()
    Dim objTable As New DataTable("ProjectInfoClass")
    objTable = objWebService.BindProjectInfo

    projectInfoList.Clear()
    For Each dr As DataRow In objTable.Rows
        projectInfoList.Add(New ProjectInfoClass With {.ProjectNumber = dr("ProjectNumber").ToString(), .ProjectId = dr("ProjectId").ToString(), .ProjectName = dr("ProjectName").ToString(), .ProjectModifiedDate = dr("ProjectModifiedDate").ToString(), .RecordUpdatedDate = dr("RecordUpdatedDate").ToString(), .ProjectLocation = dr("ProjectLocation").ToString(), .LocationServerName = dr("LocationServerName").ToString(), .ProjectModifiedBy = dr("ProjectModifiedBy").ToString(), .DBServer = dr("DBServer").ToString(), .DBName = dr("DBName").ToString(), .Flag = Nothing})
    Next
   GridView1.DataSource = objTable
    GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

### Save method

```
 For Each objectList In projectInfoList

        If objectList.Dirty = True And objectList.Flag = Nothing Then
            objWebService.UpdateProjectInfo(objectList)
            Label1.Text = "Record updated successfully"

        ElseIf objectList.Flag = "I" And objectList.Dirty = True Then
            objWebService.InsertProjectInfo(objectList)
            Label1.Text = "Record inserted successfully"
        End If
    Next

    BindData()

    btnEdit.Enabled = True
    btnSave.Enabled = False
    btnAddNewRow.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Here is the code behind to bind dropdown which calls the web method:

```
Public Sub BindDataDropDown()
     For Each grdRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.
     Dim dropDown As DropDownList = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(grdRow.RowIndex).Cells(7).FindControl("ddlProjectModifiedBy"), DropDownList)
      dropDown.DataSource = objWebService.BindDropDown()
      dropDown.DataValueField = "EmpId"
      dropDown.DataTextField = "EmpName"
      dropDown.DataBind()
     Next
End Sub
```

### rowdatabound

```
 Protected Sub ddlProjectModifiedBy_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    BindDataDropDown()
 End Sub
```

### indexchange

```
 Protected Sub ddlProjectModifiedBy_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim gv As DropDownList = TryCast(sender, DropDownList)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = gv.Parent.NamingContainer
    Dim rowindex As Integer = row.RowIndex
    projectInfoList.Item(rowindex).ProjectModifiedBy = gv.SelectedItem.ToString()
    projectInfoList.Item(rowindex).Dirty = True
End Sub
```

What should i write in the rowbound event of grid to hold selected data of dropdown in gridview?

Comment: When are you calling the `BindDataDropDown()` method? What is the content of your `Page_Load`?

Comment: Where is the WebMethod? How can you use controls in server side if its a `WebMethod`? What did you mean by `WebMethod`?

Comment: I am calling the BindDataDropDown() in Rowdatabound evnt-@Andy Refuerzo

Comment: WebMethod is inside webservice page i am calling it in code behind page as mentioned above.@subin Jacob

Answer (score 0):

Call the drop down binding method `BindDataDropDown()` after you have successfully saved the changes to the database.

Comment: @son - okay, maybe I am not understanding what you are doing. Are you capturing the selected index changed event for the drop down list and then saving the selected value of the drop down list to the database?

Comment: @son - can you post all of your code? Also, please post the logic for retrieving the list of objects you are using to bind the grid view.

Comment: Here is my whole code except web service and class which have all properties